# Can't access object method - Node.JS, Twilio, Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, twilio

I'm running a Twilio app on Heroku and am trying to setup a simple POST request to receive incoming text messages. For some reason, I am getting an error that states:

```
"TypeError: Object #<RestClient> has no method 'validateExpressRequest'"
```

I have checked several examples and the API documentation, but am unsure why I can't access the method 'validateExpressRequest'.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var accountSid = 'xxx';
var authToken = "xxx";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
});

//Create a route to resp
app.post('/respondToSms', function(req,res) {
    //Validate that this request came from TW
    if(client.validateExpressRequest(req, authToken)) {
        var twiml = new client.TwimlResponse();

        twiml.Sms('Hi, thanks for sending!');

        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
    }
    else {
        res.send('you are not twilio.');
    }
});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, taking a look at [here](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/#validateExpressRequest), seems that `validateExpressRequest` is a function of `twilio` rather than `RestClient`.

Try this:

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
...
if(twilio.validateExpressRequest(req, authToken)) {
...
```

Comment: Work! Thanks so much. Can you explain where it was getting hung up?

Comment: As explained in the 1st line of answer. If you take a look at the API reference you'll see that `validateExpressRequest` is a util function of `twilio`, not a function of `twilio.RestClient` which you were trying to call.